# Render issue - Model doesn't appear to be on any layers and won't render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Really odd on this... using Blender 2.75... I started modelling and lost the objects from the 3d view, but they were still showing in the object lists on the outlier... I was able to copy them and continued working... when I did a test render I discovered that only the original lost objects were rendering and nothing that I had modelled over the previous 2/3hrs was showing up...

I have no idea what I did but I created another 3d view and the original bits showed up along with the layer buttons which had been missing from the screen which I thought was just a new feature from  2.75...!

Picture to show the 2 screens, top one doesn't render but bottom one does

[image]

Any idea's what I've done?

Comment: Layers icon panel doesn't apper when you are in Local View (as in the top window) so don't worry about that...it is strange that there are more object in local view that in the other...providing the blendfile would be helpful in this case. Could you upload it?

Comment: Is there any "view clipping border" set?

Comment: You could accidentally hit `Numpad /` key, making currently selected object/-s be in Local View. Pressing that button again will exit Local View and reveal possibility to render those objects (or hitting `M`, it'll ask you to move out from Local View)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it was a simple mistake - I entered *Local view*, by mistake; to exit it, I just had to press <kbd>Numpad /</kbd>.