# Why did my mesh disappeared?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm a begginer in blender, so please forgive me if the question looks silly to you!

Almost all the objects in my scene disappeared (except 2) as if I deleted them by mistake. The thing is all the objects are still listed in the right side graph. The all have the eye button activated, but yet nothing is visible anymore! As I don't have a backup file, I simply can't find any tricks to fix this...

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Try hitting ALT+H to unhide everything. (H hides them) or hit the slash on number pad. Also make sure you have your layers visible at the bottom of 3D screen.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33966/render-issue-model-doesnt-appear-to-be-on-any-layers-and-wont-render?lq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have entered into the local view by mistake pressing <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> key (slash). Press <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> again to exit Local view.